# How to print fractions in a function using range and string formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, string-formatting

> Write a function `displayFractions()` that has one integer parameter: `n`. The function will DISPLAY (not return) the fractions for 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, …, n/n. The function must use `range()` function in the `for` loop and format string to display exactly 3 decimal places. The width does not have to be specified, so that number is not required. The values should print on the same line, each value separated with a comma followed by a space

Here's what I've got:

```
def displayFractions(n):
    for i in range(n, n+1):
        print('{:.3f}'.format(1/i, i/i), end=', ')
```

I know I have the wrong arguments for `range()` and `format()` but I have absolutely no idea what to plug in there. I've read and re-read the textbook and looked at dozens of examples and cannot figure this out.

Comment: This question is structured exceedingly similarly to a homework prompt.

Comment: @dpwilson: so? Is there anything specific about that structure that requires commenting on?

Comment: As discussed here [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10826#10826], is it not best practice to mention if something is part of an assignment so the answers can be more relevantly tailored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
def displayFractions(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print('{:.3f}'.format(i/n, i/i), end=', ')
```

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Since somebody already fixed your code, I'll give an answer which uses some other neat things in Python.

```
def displayFractions(n):
    print(', '.join( '{:.3f}'.format(i/n) for i in range(1, n+1) ))
```

The `str.join` method is very helpful for inserting text between items in an iterable. For example:

```
>>> ', '.join(range(10))
'0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'
```

In my function, a generator is being passed to the `str.join` method. This avoids creating an intermediate list for the fractions.

Comment: Or for funsies, use `*` unpacking and let `print` add the commas: `print(*('{:.3f}'.format(i/n) for i in range(1, n+1)), sep=', ')` :-) Side-note: `str.join` actually converts any input that's not a `tuple` or `list` to a `list` internally, discarding the `list` when it's done, so it's not actually avoiding the intermediate `list`. Similarly, the generator expression I unpack in my code is unpacking to a `tuple`, so it's not really lazy.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You only have *one* placeholder slot on your string, so you pass in just one argument. Your `range()` should start at 1 (the first argument):

```
def displayFractions(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print('{:.3f}'.format(1/i), end=', ')
```

This does print *one extra comma*. You could ignore the last iteration in the loop and just add one extra `print()` call outside the loop to print the last fraction:

```
def displayFractions(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        print('{:.3f}'.format(1/i), end=', ')
    print('{:.3f}'.format(1/n))
```